# Rewrite nginx url specific location url with PHP

Tags: php, nginx

I'm trying to rewrite a location to https.

However I only want to do this at this specific location: http://test.org/forums/dfjk34dkk25cm369aa135cs56v34/

I only want the php files in that directory to be redirected to https.

My current attempt hasn't worked out. What have I done wrong?

```
location ~ /forums/dfjk34dkk25cm369aa135cs56v34\.php(/|$) {

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick.

```
location ~ ^/forums/dfjk34dkk25cm369aa135cs56v34/.*php(/|$) {
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```